# THREE.js - Colours getting messed up on update of vertices

Tags: three.js

I'm new to Three.js, and as such I think I'm missing the required terminology to successfully google myself out of this mess.

I have a mesh I generate from an array of arrays. It looks good on load, but then I set the `THREE.Geometry` object's vertices and faces to new content with the same dimensions, but different positions.

Things that don't work, as far as I can see:

- `verticesNeedUpdate`
- `colorsNeedUpdate`
- `uvsNeedUpdate`

Here are screenshots of before and after:

[image]

[image]

Please don't shame my shitty pyramids. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some of your code?

Comment: Yep, thanks Chris. Here's the github repo at the commit in question: https://github.com/andrewcarreiro/terrain-generator/tree/d3cac537e21a4daa9d570617f01c7e9440090280 The THREE.js code occurs in terrainmap.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after using Chrome dev tools to walk through every possible variable and function, I found it.

The solution is that the `THREE.Geometry()` needed to have the following flag set after each vertex update: `my_geometry_object.normalsNeedUpdate = true;`

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner too... When I had to update my scene (after adding lights so it is different...) I used :

```
    function updateMaterials(scene) {
        scene.traverse(function (node) {
            if (node.material) {
                node.material.needsUpdate = true;
                if (node.material instanceof THREE.MeshFaceMaterial) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < node.material.materials.length; i++) {
                        node.material.materials[i].needsUpdate = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

It is maybe exactly what you do when you set the your "NeedUpdate" ?